# System.EnterpriseServies.Wrapper.dll missing in Powershell Work Flow

Tags: powershell-remoting, powershell-3.0

I run Server 2008 R2 as a workstation (mainly to get Hyper-V IIS 7.5). I’ve been playing around with this system for a while and it’s hardly pure! ;-)

Today, I loaded the latest set of patches, and took the reboot opportunity to add the rtm version of PowerShell v3. I duly removed the PowerShell V3 beta, applied the monthly patches, rebooted, then added the new version of PowerShell and rebooted again.

However, I now have an issue: Anytime I try to run a workflow, I get:

**PSH [C:\foo]: Provision-AD    # Run the workflow
The workflow ' Provision-AD ' could not be started: Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its
dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
At line:321 char:21
+                     throw (New-Object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Manageme...etersDictionary:PSBoundParametersDictionary) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartWorkflow.InvalidArgument**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy. I did a re-install of the .NET Framework 4.0 and all is now well!